# Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, , >= - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables `alerte` and `quittance_alerte` that have a many-to-one relationship.

I'm trying to insert a new record into the `alerte` table and insert other records (from a select query) into `quittance_alerte` with the `alerte_Id` I just inserted.

I get this exception :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here is my code :

```
insert into [PrimesCXP_DB].[dbo].[alerte] (desc_alerte_id, Contenu, statut)
values (1, 'desc', '1')

declare @alerte_id int 

set @alerte_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM [PrimesCXP_DB].[dbo].[alerte])

insert into [PrimesCXP_DB].[dbo].[quittancier_alerte] (numero_quittance, alerte_id)
values ((SELECT NUMERO_QUITTANCE
         FROM [PCXP_Proassur_PreProd].[dbo].[QUITTANCIER]
         WHERE ETAT_MVT IN (0, 2, 4, 5, 7) 
           AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_EFFET, GETDATE()) > 65
           AND (DATE_RNP IS NULL OR DATE_RNP = '01/01/1900')
           AND tERME_COMPTANT IN ('T', 'C')), @alerte_id)
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: But here i must insert multiple rows .. is there an alternative to do it?

Comment: Also: **DO NOT** do this: `set @alerte_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM [PrimesCXP_DB].[dbo].[alerte])` - use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function instead: `SET @alerte_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to really get the last inserted `id` value back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
SELECT NUMERO_QUITTANCE
FROM [PCXP_Proassur_PreProd].[dbo].[QUITTANCIER]
WHERE ETAT_MVT IN (0, 2, 4, 5, 7)
  AND    DATEDIFF(day, DATE_EFFET, GETDATE())>65
  AND   ( DATE_RNP is null or DATE_RNP = '01/01/1900')
  AND tERME_COMPTANT in ('T', 'C')
```

returns multiple rows, and you're trying to use it like it returns only one. If it should return multiple rows, you can insert multiple rows by updating your insert statement thus:

```
INSERT INTO [PrimesCXP_DB].[dbo].[quittancier_alerte]
( numero_quittance, alerte_id)
SELECT NUMERO_QUITTANCE, @alerte_id
  FROM [PCXP_Proassur_PreProd].[dbo].[QUITTANCIER]
  WHERE ETAT_MVT IN (0, 2, 4, 5, 7)
  AND DATEDIFF(day, DATE_EFFET, GETDATE())>65
  AND ( DATE_RNP is null or DATE_RNP = '01/01/1900')
  AND tERME_COMPTANT in ('T', 'C')
```

Otherwise you need to figure out how to make the subquery return only a single row.